# Counting Numbers within a cell

Tags: excel

Currently I am trying to figure out the number of purchases within one year. In my QTY purchased cell I have a list of quantities (800+2400+2400+2400+2400+2400+2400). This cell shows 7 different purchases.

My question is, what formula will take this cell and count the number of purchases individually and spit out 7 for the number of purchases, without me having to count them manually??

I have tried using both Len and Count formulas, however, they continue to either count the characters or just the cell itself.

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: I think you are probably structuring your spreadsheet wrong. If you have 7 different quantities you would be better off having them in 7 different cells and then use a formula to sum the range of cells. This may be best done on a separate sheet (Eg PurchaseDetails) and then you can see at a glance all your purchases without having to look at the formula and you can also then add them, count them and do anything else you want with them.

Comment: Looking back, it would have been easier to keep all the purchases separate and use a pivot table to count the amount of purchases, however, we went ahead and combined all the same items into one line item in order to condense and make the sheet much more easy to read.

Comment: To help explain that further, we did at one point have 7 different cells for each purchase but condensed all the quantities into one cell for visual purposes

Comment: Well I suspect there are no built in formulae that easily do what you want so you'll need to do complicated things with splitting the string up and counting the elements. I'd personally seriously consider expanding them into separate sheets as I've described. Your master sheet (ie the one you have currently) can then just refer to the sum and the count of the table on the new sheet.

Comment: Or the other option is using hidden columns or rows to hide the details and just show the summaries without needing to screw up your data.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should probably structure your worksheet differently, as highlighted by Chris in the comments.
2. If you want to keep it that way, you can use a user-defined function in a VBA module to retrieve the formula text and then use that to count the number of "+" signs.

   ```
   Public Function FormulaText(rng As Range)

   FormulaText = rng.formula

   End Function
   ```

A counting formula could be:

```
=len(formulatext(a1))-len(substitute(formulatext(a1),"+",""))+1
```

Comment: Ugly but it works. I wouldn't want to have to rely on this though.

Comment: It's gotten slightly more reliable as the "newer" versions of excel replace a starting + sign by the equal sign, but indeed not as reliable as a clean dataset.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula didn't work for me..is there something I should change with the quantity formula?

Comment: did you save the function in a module of the workbook? Does the `formulatext()` part work if you use it on its own? What result do you get?

Comment: I think that you need to change the return statement to `FormulaText = rng.formula`